# Function to generate access token to be used in web service authentication

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, access-token

I need a php function that generates access token to uniquely identify users. I will store this token in an extra column named "token" and I will use it for authentication with mobile app. I searched for it online and all results refer to either twitter or facebook. I need it in my app.

I use cakePHP backend and Android platform.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

using guid :-

```
function getGUID(){
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid')){
        return com_create_guid();
    }else{
        mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $hyphen = chr(45);// "-"
        $uuid = chr(123)// "{"
            .substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
            .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,20,12)
            .chr(125);// "}"
        return $uuid;
    }
}

$GUID = getGUID();
echo $GUID;
```

or refer this link http://guid.us/GUID/PHP

Answer (score -1):

You can also use rendomaly generate token like below using php.

```
$length = 20;

function generate_password($length)
{
    if($length>0) 
    {
        $rand_id="";
        for($i=1; $i<=$length; $i++)
        {
            mt_srand((double)microtime() * 1000000);
            $num = mt_rand(1,36);
            $rand_id .= $this->assign_rand_value($num);
        }
    }
    return $rand_id;
}

function assign_rand_value($num)
{
    switch($num)
    {
        case "1":
            $rand_value = "a";
        break;
        case "2":
            $rand_value = "b";
        break;
        case "3":
            $rand_value = "c";
        break;
        case "4":
            $rand_value = "d";
        break;
        case "5":
            $rand_value = "e";
        break;
        case "6":
            $rand_value = "f";
        break;
        case "7":
            $rand_value = "g";
        break;
        case "8":
            $rand_value = "h";
        break;
        case "9":
            $rand_value = "i";
        break;
        case "10":
            $rand_value = "j";
        break;
        case "11":
            $rand_value = "k";
        break;
        case "12":
            $rand_value = "l";
        break;
        case "13":
            $rand_value = "m";
        break;
        case "14":
            $rand_value = "n";
        break;
        case "15":
            $rand_value = "o";
        break;
        case "16":
            $rand_value = "p";
        break;
        case "17":
            $rand_value = "q";
        break;
        case "18":
            $rand_value = "r";
        break;
        case "19":
            $rand_value = "s";
        break;
        case "20":
            $rand_value = "t";
        break;
        case "21":
            $rand_value = "u";
        break;
        case "22":
            $rand_value = "v";
        break;
        case "23":
            $rand_value = "w";
        break;
        case "24":
            $rand_value = "x";
        break;
        case "25":
            $rand_value = "y";
        break;
        case "26":
            $rand_value = "z";
        break;
        case "27":
            $rand_value = "0";
        break;
        case "28":
            $rand_value = "1";
        break;
        case "29":
            $rand_value = "2";
        break;
        case "30":
            $rand_value = "3";
        break;
        case "31":
            $rand_value = "4";
        break;
        case "32":
            $rand_value = "5";
        break;
        case "33":
            $rand_value = "6";
        break;
        case "34":
            $rand_value = "7";
        break;
        case "35":
            $rand_value = "8";
        break;
        case "36":
            $rand_value = "9";
        break;
    }
    return $rand_value;
}
```

This will generate 20 character random token.

Then you can call it like

```
$link = $this->generate_password(20);
```

Comment: Considered a different method instead of all that switch...case...break? Like having a string labeled `$chars="abcde...456789"` and just getting `substr($chars, strlen($chars)-1, 1)` repeatedly?